# How to isolate the domain name from a URL?

Tags: php, urlparse

I'm looking for a method (or function) to strip out the `example.ext` part of any URL that's fed into the function. The domain extension can be anything (.com, .co.uk, .nl, .whatever), and the URL that's fed into it can be anything from `http://www.example.com` to `www.example.com/path/script.php?=whatever`

What's the best way to go about doing this?

I'd like `example.com`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Getting Domain Name From Subdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201194/php-getting-domain-name-from-subdomain)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

[parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) turns a URL into an associative array:

```
php > $foo = "http://www.example.com/foo/bar?hat=bowler&accessory=cane";
php > $blah = parse_url($foo);
php > print_r($blah);
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.example.com
    [path] => /foo/bar
    [query] => hat=bowler&accessory=cane
)
```

Comment: What would be the best way to strip out the www. portion if its present in the domain. IM not good with regex. The messy way I can think of is 
$www_check = substr($domain,0,4);  
if ($www_check == "www.") { 
echo substr($domain, 4); 
} else { echo $domain; }

Comment: @Yegor: $domain = preg_replace('/^www./','',$domain);

Comment: I like explode on "www." and then use the first instance in the array myself.  It generally works just fine.

Comment: Careful Robert as a lot of URls don't have www in front of them. ie images.google.com

Comment: Yeah, generally for my purposes, that's the goal, as a non-www subdomain is pretty informative about the content being displayed in that part of the site.

Comment: Slight problem with your suggestion, Robert. It wont find the host if there is no http:// in the url.

Comment: You can check if the URL has starts with HTTP by doing - if (strpos($url, 'http://') === 0); you can also do the same for HTTPS, if it doesn't have it, you can add it and then run it through parse_url.

Answer (score 14):

You can use [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to do this:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$domain = str_replace('www.','',$domain);
```

In this example, $domain should contain example.com, irrespective of it having www or not. It also works for a domain such as .co.uk

Comment: Shouldn't that be parse_url() instead of url_parse()

Comment: Note: the second argument for parse_url is a PHP5 invention. Anyone on PHP4 (upgrade, please, for the love of God...) will need to use Robert Elwell's way.

Comment: Anyone on PHP4 ... will have to upgrade.

Comment: $domain contains www.example.com.

Answer (score 14):

You can also write a regular expression to get exactly what you want.

Here is my attempt at it:

```
$pattern = '/\w+\..{2,3}(?:\..{2,3})?(?:$|(?=\/))/i';
$url = 'http://www.example.com/foo/bar?hat=bowler&accessory=cane';
if (preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches) === 1) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

The output is:

```
example.com
```

This pattern also takes into consideration domains such as 'example.com.au'.

Note: I have not consulted the relevant RFC.

Comment: Can I use this regex pattern in another language?

Answer (score 7):

Following code will trim protocol, domain and port from absolute URL:

```
$urlWithoutDomain = preg_replace('#^.+://[^/]+#', '', $url);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple simple functions to get the root domain (example.com) from a normal or long domain (test.sub.domain.com) or url (http://www.example.com).

```
/**
 * Get root domain from full domain
 * @param string $domain
 */
public function getRootDomain($domain)
{
    $domain = explode('.', $domain);

    $tld = array_pop($domain);
    $name = array_pop($domain);

    $domain = "$name.$tld";

    return $domain;
}

/**
 * Get domain name from url
 * @param string $url
 */
public function getDomainFromUrl($url)
{
    $domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $domain = $this->getRootDomain($domain);

    return $domain;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this...

Say we're calling dev.mysite.com and we want to extract 'mysite.com'

```
$requestedServerName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; // = dev.mysite.com

$thisSite = explode('.', $requestedServerName); // site name now an array

array_shift($thisSite); //chop off the first array entry eg 'dev'

$thisSite = join('.', $thisSite); //join it back together with dots ;)

echo $thisSite; //outputs 'mysite.com'
```

Works with mysite.co.uk too so should work everywhere :)

Comment: Does not work with with 2 part TLDs unless you have a subdomain as well.

`www.mydomain.co.uk // outputs 'mydomain.co.uk'
    mydomain.co.uk // outputs co.uk`

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time thinking about whether it makes sense to use a regular expression for this, but in the end I think not.

firstresponder's regexp came close to convincing me it was the best way, but it didn't work on anything missing a trailing slash (so http://example.com, for instance). I fixed that with the following: `'/\w+\..{2,3}(?:\..{2,3})?(?=[\/\W])/i'`, but then I realized that matches twice for urls like 'http://example.com/index.htm'. Oops. That wouldn't be so bad (just use the first one), but it also matches twice on something like this: 'http://abc.ed.fg.hij.kl.mn/', and the first match isn't the right one.  :(

A co-worker suggested just getting the host (via `parse_url()`), and then just taking the last two or three array bits (`split()` on '.') The two or three would be based on a list of domains, like 'co.uk', etc. Making up that list becomes the hard part.

Answer (score 0):

This function should work:

```
function Delete_Domain_From_Url($Url = false)
{
    if($Url)
    {
        $Url_Parts = parse_url($Url);
        $Url = isset($Url_Parts['path']) ? $Url_Parts['path'] : '';
        $Url .= isset($Url_Parts['query']) ? "?".$Url_Parts['query'] : '';
    }

    return $Url;
}
```

To use it:

```
$Url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176284/how-do-you-strip-out-the-domain-name-from-a-url-in-php";
echo Delete_Domain_From_Url($Url);

# Output: 
#/questions/176284/how-do-you-strip-out-the-domain-name-from-a-url-in-php
```

Answer (score -1):

There is only one correct way to extract domain parts, it's use [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/) (database of TLDs). I recomend [TLDExtract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract) package, here is sample code:

```
$extract = new LayerShifter\TLDExtract\Extract();

$result = $extract->parse('www.domain.com/path/script.php?=whatever');
$result->getSubdomain(); // will return (string) 'www'
$result->getHostname(); // will return (string) 'domain'
$result->getSuffix(); // will return (string) 'com'
```