# How to make dynamic Product URL key in phtml file for magento shop

Tags: php, magento, url

I want to make a "shop online" link on the B2B Magento shop product page (*http://b2b.com/product1/*) to redirect visitors to the B2C shop product page like: *http://b2c.com/product1/*

I only know that `<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>` is calling *http://b2b.com/product1/* But how to call a dynamic URL key in the */product/view.phtml*, so then in the URL structure only the domain is changed from *b2b.com* to *b2c.com* but the product key will stay the same according to which product is being viewed?

Comment: If you can post some of your existing code or attempts to solve this it'll be easier to suggest how to fix any problems or improve the approach.

Comment: my best guess is '<p><a title="<?php echo $this->__('Online Shop') ?>" href="http://b2c.com/<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Online Shop') ?></span></span></a></p>'

Comment: But the link shows http://b2c.com/b2b.com/product1/, how to remove the b2b.com and just leave the /product1/ in the URL structure?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176284/how-do-you-strip-out-the-domain-name-from-a-url-in-php | The parse_url function should be helpful to you too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution that is exactly what I want to achieve:

`<a href="http://google.com/<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()) ?><?php echo $_product->getUrlKey(); ?>">ProductName</a>`

Then the URL link will be shown as google.com/ProductName