# Replace value of specific URL param in PHP

Tags: php, url, substring, str-replace

I have a Facebook link string:

```
"https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?client_id=*****&state=*****&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.1.2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Ffacebook%2Flink&scope=email%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_photos"
```

I want to replace:

`redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888`

to

`redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost`

---

I would do something like this if it's the browser URL, but it is a string inside a anchor tag.

```
if (isset($_GET['redirect_uri'])) {
    echo $_GET['redirect_uri'];
}else{
    // Fallback behaviour goes here
}
```

How do I do something like that?

---

I've tried

```
$permissions = 'user_birthday,user_photos';
$login_url = $fb->getLoginUrl(['email','scope'=>$permissions]);
$urls = explode("&", $login_url);
$redirect_uri = explode("=", $urls[4]);
$link = explode("%2F", $redirect_uri[1]);

dd($link);

// array:5 [▼
//   0 => "http%3A"
//   1 => ""
//   2 => "localhost%3A8888" // I want to replace this string with 'localhost'
//   3 => "facebook"
//   4 => "link"
// ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe some regex replacement?

```
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?client_id=*****&state=*****&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.1.2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Ffacebook%2Flink&scope=email%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_photos';

$pattern = '/redirect_uri=http\%3A\%2F\%2F[\%0-9A-Za-z]+facebook/';
$replace = 'redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ffacebook';
$newURl = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your string is actually `redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888` then do this:

```
$url = $_GET['redirect_uri'];
$url = str_replace('redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888', 'redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost', $url);
```

This will search the string and make the required changes, then save it back to the `$url` variable.

Obviously, you could use `$_GET['redirect_uri']`, either way you should sanitise the input:

[Filter Input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

[Filters - Sanitise](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: the `redirect_uri` is not alway `= http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888` . I'm sorry. I updated my post.

Comment: My exact **goal** to replace `'redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F----anything---'` with `'redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost'`

Comment: So if the domain URI was `http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com/foo` you'd want it to be replaced with `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost/foo`?

Comment: `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost/foo` , and It's a string. It's not a URL Param.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176284/how-do-you-strip-out-the-domain-name-from-a-url-in-php might get you started, you'll need str_replace and a regex of some description I think

Comment: marcellorvalle nailed it for you I think!

Answer (score 1):

Considering this input string:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?client_id=*****&state=*****&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.1.2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Ffacebook%2Flink&scope=email%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_photos
```

You can use this flexible regex pattern with an empty replacement string:

```
/&redirect_uri=\S+?localhost\K%[^%]+/
```

[Replacement Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/1dpjTI/1)

This pattern (in plain terms) says:

- match "&redirect_uri="
- match any non-white-character one or more times (stopping as soon as possible)
- match "localhost"
- restart the "full string match" (`\K`)
- match "%"
- match one or more non-% characters