# how to turn ?page=home to ?home and still use $_GET

Tags: php

Is there anyway to turn index.php?page=home to just index.php?home, so I can still use $_GET? or is this impossible? I would have googled this but I couldn't find anything anywhere.
**UPDATE** let me be more clear, i need to get the string AFTER index.php? so i can use it in my php code

Comment: I think you can use `index.php?home`, check using `isset($_GET['home'])`, but the downside is `home` does no have any value, or at least that's what I know

Comment: i need to be able to get the string "home" or whatever string is after index.php?

Comment: Does `isset($_GET['home']) ? 'Home' : '';` suffice?

Comment: If the server is run by Apache this is usually done with .htaccess and mod_rewrite – that should give some keywords to google with. Although it's more common to shorten it directly to example.com/home instead of example.com/index.php?home.

Comment: @Swellar it needs to be dynamic, as in index.php?home can be anything like index.php?string, index.php?r94fr904jughg etc.

Comment: You mean without redirect?

Comment: @JJJ mod_rewrite still wont help, i need the string after index.php?

Comment: If you only need a string after a certain character use `substr()`. I think you are not explaining What you need to achieve and what the problem is in the first place very well.

Comment: @odedta yes, im making a chat where anyone can make a chat with any string

Comment: Use this then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/176341/4711865 - or just substr to get a part of a string

Comment: Uh, that's exactly what mod_rewrite does. It rewrites index.php?xxx to index.php?page=xxx.

Comment: @JJJ thats NOT what i want, i want the string to turn into a VARIABLE i can use

Comment: @odedta thanks, this works. i would accept your answer but its a comment

Comment: Jesus christ. What exactly do you then think that mod_rewrite does? When the user types example.com/index.php?home into the browser, mod_rewrite turns the URL *internally* (i.e. invisible to the user) into example.com/index.php?page=home. That way you get the variable from `$_GET['page']`.

Comment: @JJJ, I think he means that he wants to use any string inside a chat app, not necessarily the address bar. Does mod_rewrite change any string typed by the user anywhere and sent to server or only in the address bar?

Comment: @odedta I don't know what you mean by "typed by the user anywhere" – if you mean Ajax calls, then yes, the server doesn't know/care how the request was made.

Comment: @JJJ For example, yes. I see, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the URL and string the hostname out you can use [Robert Elwell answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176284/how-do-you-strip-out-the-domain-name-from-a-url-in-php/176341#176341)

```
$foo = "http://www.example.com/foo/bar?hat=bowler&accessory=cane";
$blah = parse_url($foo);
print_r($blah);
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.example.com
    [path] => /foo/bar
    [query] => hat=bowler&accessory=cane
)
```

If you want to use any string you could use `[substr][2]` to return only a part of a string.

If you have a more concrete example I could give an example on how to solve it.